# Why is MonkeyRunner failing with Bad type on operand error?

Tags: android, ubuntu, monkeyrunner

On Ubuntu 18.04, I installed MonkeyRunner via `sudo apt install monkeyrunner`, and it completed successfully.

I created a file called `test.py` and wrote the content

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
```

I connected my phone over USB, enabled USB debugging, then executed the program with `monkeyrunner test.py` but I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/android/monkeyrunner/ScriptRunner.console(Ljava/lang/String;)V @13: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/python/util/JLineConsole' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/python/util/InteractiveConsole'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @13
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String', 'org/python/util/JLineConsole' }
    stack: { 'org/python/util/JLineConsole' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab8 0035 bb00 5159 b700 524c 2bb6 0053
    0x0000010: b1                                     

    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:73)
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

What is causing this, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @user3046442 no, I ended up pushing touch commands directly from adb. I'm not sure if I still have the files though, this was for a dumb bot project auto-playing a dumb Android game. I was bored :D

Comment: Thanks @user3046442 mine finally worked. Had to reinstall android studio and SDK tools and switched to java 8 :) And yes you can  directly send touch commands from adb as well.

Answer (score 0):

Install Android studio with this command:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

After that you can find "monkeyrunner" at this path:

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
```

Comment: There's no need to install the entire AndroidStudio, the AndroidSDK is sufficient